# Loading an iFrame Instance on Top of Another iFrame Instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have 3 iFrames on my page.  The first iFrame takes up the left 45% of the page.  The second iFrame takes up the right 45% of the page.  I would like to load a third iFrame that takes up the middle 45% of the page (it would load last and partially cover the other 2 iFrames).  After adding the 3rd iFrame, I noticed that instead of loading on top of the other 2 iFrames, it pushed itself to the bottom of the page.  Is there a way to get an iFrame to load on top of another iFrame?

My CSS:

```
.right {
        float: right;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #006400;
       }
#iframe1 {
          width: 181%; 
          height: 182%; 
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          zoom: 1.00; 
          -moz-transform: scale(0.55); 
          -moz-transform-orgin: 0 0;
          -o-transform: scale(0.55); 
          -o-transform-origin: 0 0; 
          -webkit-transform: scale(0.55); 
          -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
         }
#frame1 {
              float: left;
              width: 45%; 
              height: 75%; 
              top: 10%;
              left: 2%;
              margin: 10px; 
              border-style: solid; 
              border-width: 10px;
         }         
#frame2 {
              float: right;
              width: 45%; 
              height: 75%; 
              top: 10%;
              right: 2%;
              margin: 10px; 
              border-style: solid; 
              border-width: 10px;
         }
.frame3 {
            float: center;
            width: 45%;
            height: 75%;
            top: 10%;
            left: 27.5%;
            margin: 10px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
        }
```

My HTML:

```
<div class = 'right'>
<div id = 'frame1'>
      <iframe id = 'iframe1' src = 'http://www.wsj.com'></iframe></div>
<div id = 'frame2'>
      <iframe id = 'iframe1' src = 'http://www.wsj.com'></iframe></div>
<div id = 'frame3'>
      <iframe id = 'iframe1' src = 'http://www.wsj.com'></iframe></div>
<br><br><br>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.frame3{
    position:absolute;
        top:10%;
        left:27.5%;
    width:45%;
    //other properties
}
```

because of the absolute position, you'll want to ensure it constrains within it's parent container (if that *is* the intended effect)

```
.right{
    position:relative;
    //other properties
}
```